# Amount of Data Calculated in a Game

Tags: 2d, software-engineering, memory-efficiency

So... I am theorizing the development of a 2d living persistent fullsized world with simulated ecossystem, etc..., and many, many objects, but how can I handle the giant amount of data that will be calculated per instance.
I mean, as the ecossystem is simulated and alive, animals would roam, plants would grow the climate would change etc... I already planned on how to implement the simulated ecossystem, but I wanted them to happen all at once, not in separated instances like World of Warcraft's dungeons or different maps. Just one entire and fullsized chunck with all the things happening on it.

Is it possible, even for an extreme low graphical game? I know of games that do something like it. Eg.: Dwarf Fortress, but what I am aiming for is way bigger than that.

EDIT:
For the "AI", I was planning on do behavioral intelligent organization or BIO, something I am planning and theorizating. It would be like a giant The Sims, every object(animal, plant, etc...) would have it's needs, characteristics, possibilities and impossibilities, they need to eat so they interact with the enviroment and with other objects on their own with modified version of A* lead by his senses(vision, audition, ect...). I know it is complicated and not polished, its because I am still studying everything and I'm more like a amateur programmer.

Comment: 510M km^2 with dense population simulated all at once on a PC?

Comment: I'd recommend splitting the world in chunks, do the real simulation in the active one and those nearby and then figure out some good approximation for the others, based on time and the outcome of the nearby chunks by simulating the whole world. Remember, what player can't see doesn't have to be exact - only believable.

Comment: Is it for a game or for a simulation? What kind of user interaction do you need?

Comment: Point and click, much like a Civilization's game, but with many more details and you would control only one character and it's assets. I thought about separating the world in chuncks, but I'll also have to decide how many chuncks, and their size, even knowing how I could relate them to one another. The world in question is a little bigger than earth, I can't say the same for the population.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not at least from what you're describing.

An AI that's unique to one animal that takes into account all of the variables of such a complex environment would be taxing to simulate just on it's own. Plant life would be easier, but the cost to simulate all the plants would add up fast. A continuous simulation of the entire ecosystem would be virtually impossible to achieve without faking most of it.

Essentially, you wouldn't be able to do the simulation outside of the immediate area of the player, unless you make the simulation dirt cheap. And at that point, the computing power would be so stretched out across all the parts of the world that the simulation wouldn't really even be a simulation anymore.

But instead of that, I'd recommend just not doing it. Using the computing power towards the part of the game the player is actively engaging in would be better than running some simulation in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Simulating the whole world in real time on a single PC is unlikely to be possible.

What you could do, however, is split your world in several chunks (I mean chunks, not shards). You'd have to adapt your world for an agent (AI) to be able to exist in a single chunk at any given time. For instance, you could have one big island per chunk.

And then you could have one computer per chunk that manage the simulation. For that much stuff to simulate, I would suggest you use a very low frame rate, i.e. 1-2 Hz. Your game servers would be somehow all connected together, with a master server that stores data. And you'd need a way for your simulated agents to transfer from one chunk to another (like a mega teleporter bridge or something).

A thing you could do: if a player is in a chunk, set your simulation speed to a higher frame rate (4 Hz, for instance), while if no one is there reduce it to a lower frame rate (i.e. 0.5 Hz).

Of course, you'd have carefully decouple your graphics from your logic, and make it so that your graphics look smooth and not show that the logic is really slow.

Comment: I thought about separating it in chuncks, much like Minecraft, and outputting important things like the total population of each species within it, weather and climate information and other important events. I couldn't really say for the frame rate part as I didn't get on that part of game programming yet. The player wouldn't be able to see the simulated agents from too afar depending on its perception, so I think I could generate the graphics only of those how are in its perception arc or a little outside to prevent objects from spawning within the player screen.

Comment: I thought about calculating everything in the back process where they can't be seen and doesn't need to be draw, but only the chunck datas interaging with each other, so I could have cloud formations moving, or forest fires spreading, etc... and only show what is within or near the player screen.